# can't get post id when sharing with Facebook JS SDK on a public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK Javascript sharing. When I share a url I need to get the post id back to store and check it later.
To do so I ask in my app for the 'publish_actions' permission because according to the documentation it is needed to get the id back. 
The problem is that when the user share, if the sharing is done on the user profile I get the ID back if the sharing is done on public page no id is sent back.

I connect to my applicaion with this

```
FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            version: 'v2.7'
          });
        });
```

then when the user share I first check if they are logged in inside the app with this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                    }, {
                        scope: 'publish_actions',
                    });
```

and then I share using this

```
FB.ui({
                            method: 'share',
                            href: url

                 }, function (response) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                 });
```

And the alert at the end gives me post id if the post is on the use profile but undefined if it is on a page.

Comment: "need to get the post id back to store and check it later" - may i ask what for exactly?

Comment: about the issue: you could file a bug. it does look like one. btw, you should not use FB.ui in an asynchronous callback of FB.login - just in case you are doing that. FB.ui must be called on user interaction.

Comment: @luschn Just to collect statistics on the post later.

Comment: you will not get publish_actions approved for this...page insights are for stats.